# php fatal error when I try php artisan serve

Tags: php, laravel

Hello guys please I suddenly have this error when I try php artisan command on my laravel project

```
PHP Warning:  require_once(H:\cryptoblockspot/bootstrap/app.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in H:\cryptoblockspot\artisan on line 20

Warning: require_once(H:\cryptoblockspot/bootstrap/app.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in H:\cryptoblockspot\artisan on line 20
PHP Fatal error:  require_once(): Failed opening required 'H:\cryptoblockspot/bootstrap/app.php' (include_path='C:\xampp\php\PEAR') in H:\cryptoblockspot\artisan on line 20

Fatal error: require_once(): Failed opening required 'H:\cryptoblockspot/bootstrap/app.php' (include_path='C:\xampp\php\PEAR') in H:\cryptoblockspot\artisan on line 20
```

Please Guys I need help on this thanks in advance

Comment: Does this answer your question? [PHP - Failed to open stream : No such file or directory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36577020/php-failed-to-open-stream-no-such-file-or-directory)

Comment: Thanks @AlonEitan I've solved it but the link didn't answer my question. Fool me I just discovered that bootstrap folder on my laravel project was missing so I collected it from one of my projects and fixed it back and it worked.

Comment: correct that generic link does not help anything at all, every single error isn't a duplicate of a generic error

Answer (score -1):

Basically it is not finding the file:
H:\cryptoblockspot/bootstrap/app.php

Check if it exists and the system has access permission